# Why does dropping the ca-cert flag let redis-cli connect to our Redis server via SSL?

Tags: ssl, redis, ssl-certificate

I am using Redis 6.2.6 with TLS. I managed to provide Redis with SSL certificates (full-chain and key certificates) that are issued by ZeroSSL through Acme.sh. I got things working (after wrangling with permissions), but when I connect to the server with:

```
redis-cli -h <host>.domain.tld -p <port> --tls --cacert /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt --cert "/path/to/certs/*.domain.tld.pem" --key "/path/to/certs/*.domain.tld.key"
```

I get:

```
Could not connect to Redis at <host>.domain.tld:<port>: SSL_connect failed: certificate verify failed
```

However, when I remove the `--cacert` flag, like:

```
redis-cli -h <host>.domain.tld -p <port> --tls --cert "/path/to/certs/*.domain.tld.pem" --key "/path/to/certs/*.domain.tld.key"
```

I am able to connect successfully to the Redis server. Why is this so?

---

Here is the relevant TLS-related configuration for the Redis server.

```
port     0
tls-port <port>

tls-cert-file    /path/to/certs/*.domain.tld.pem
tls-key-file     /path/to/certs/*.domain.tld.key
tls-ca-cert-file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
tls-auth-clients no
```